# GLib-GObject-CRITICAL. Error when executing 'gulp' on fresh laravel project

Tags: laravel, centos, gulp, laravel-elixir, gulp-notify

Does anyone have a clue or any direction how to fix this error.
Running CentOS 6.7

```
[07:42 PM]-[vagrant@machine1]-[/var/www/laracast]
$ gulp
[19:42:52] Using gulpfile /var/www/laracast/gulpfile.js
[19:42:52] Starting 'default'...
[19:42:52] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
   - resources/assets/sass/app.scss


Saving To...
   - public/css/app.css

[19:42:53] Finished 'default' after 733 ms
[19:42:53] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[19:42:53] Finished 'sass' after 833 ms
[19:42:53] gulp-notify: [Error in notifier] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify'
Message:

(notify-send:24561): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable gulp notify by `export DISABLE_NOTIFIER=true`

> If you are running on a system that handles notifications poorly or you simply do not wish to use gulp-notify but your project does? You can disable gulp-notify by using enviroment variable DISABLE_NOTIFIER.
>
> export DISABLE_NOTIFIER=true;
>
> This will disable all methods; notify(), notify.onError and notify.withReporter.

See details here: [disable-gulp-notify](https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify#disable-gulp-notify)

Comment: add some explanation from the site. don't depend on the link only.